# xQuery to change node hierarchies (remove a child from one node and return it as sibling)

Tags: xml, xpath, recursion, xml-parsing, xquery

I have an xml document that looks like this:

```xml
<dict>
    <word>
        <sense>
            <definition> This is the text of the definition. 
                <example>
                    <quote>This is the text of an example.</quote>
                </example>
                <source>
                    <place>This is the name of the place recorded</place>
                </source>. 
            </definition>
        </sense>
    </word>
</dict>
```

I need to use xQuery to transform it in such a way that the `<example>` and its children become the siblings of `<definition>`, whereas `<source>` and its children should become the children of `<example>`. In other words, I need this as an output:

```xml
<word>
    <sense>
        <definition> This is the text of the definition. </definition>
        <example>
            <quote>This is the text of an example.</quote>
            <source>
                <place>This is the name of the place recorded.</place>
            </source>
        </example>
    </sense>
</word>
```

As you can see, there is also an issue with a full-stop that follows the original `<source>` element that needs to become the last string before the closure of `<place>`.

I have created an xQuery file and figured out how to remove elements from the hierarchy, but I am having trouble recursively processing nodes AND adding new elements in the same function.

```xml
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/";
declare option saxon:output "indent=yes";
declare option saxon:output "saxon:indent-spaces=3";


declare function local:test($node as item()*) as item()* {
    typeswitch($node)
        case text() return normalize-space($node)
        case element(word) return <word>{local:recurse($node)}</word>
        case element(dict) return <dict>{local:recurse($node)}</dict>
        case element(sense) return <sense>{local:recurse($node)}</sense>
        case element(definition) return local:definition($node)
        case element(example) return local:example($node)
        case element(source) return local:source($node)
        case element(place) return <place>{local:recurse($node)}</place>
        default return local:recurse($node)
};

declare function local:definition($nodes as item()*) as item()*{

(: here I need to process children of definition - except <source> and its
children will become children of <example>; and <example> should be returned 
as a next sibling of definition. THIS IS THE PART THAT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO :)

<definition>
{
 for $node in $nodes/node()
    return
        local:test($node)
}
</definition>

};

declare function local:example($node as item()*) as item()* {
(: here i am removing <example> because I don't want it to be a child
of <definition> any more. THIS BIT WORKS AS IT SHOULD :)

if ($node/parent::definition) then ()
   else <example>{$node/@*}{local:recurse($node)}</example>
};

declare function local:source($node as item()*) as item()* {
(: here i am removing <source> because I don't want it to be a child
of <definition> any more.  :)

if ($node/parent::definition) then ()
   else <example>{$node/@*}{local:recurse($node)}</example>
};


declare function local:recurse($nodes as item()*) as item()* {
    for $node in $nodes/node()
    return
        local:test($node)
};


local:test(doc("file:test.xml"))
```

This should not be a terribly difficult thing to achieve, but I am having a conceptual difficulty with how xQuery deals with this sort of problem. I'll be very grateful for your help.

XSLT is not an option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, here a working **recursive XQuery 1.0** solution with just one recursive function. I agree with Jens that the given example can be dealt with easily enough without recursion, but in case real examples are bigger, and you don't have XQuery Update at your disposal, you could try something like this:

```
declare function local:recurse($node as item()*) as item()* {
    typeswitch($node)
        case text()
            return normalize-space($node)
        case element(definition)
            return element {node-name($node)} {
                $node/@*,
                local:recurse($node/node() except $node/(example|source))
            }
        case element(sense)
            return element {node-name($node)} {
                $node/@*,
                local:recurse($node/node()),
                <example>{
                    $node/definition/example/@*,
                    $node/definition/example/node(),
                    $node/definition/source
                }</example>
            }
        case element()
            return element {node-name($node)} {
                $node/@*,
                local:recurse($node/node())
            }
        default return $node
};


let $xml :=
<dict>
    <word>
        <sense>
            <definition> This is the text of the definition. 
                <example>
                    <quote>This is the text of an example.</quote>
                </example>
                <source>
                    <place>This is the name of the place recorded.</place>
                </source>
            </definition>
        </sense>
    </word>
</dict>
return local:recurse($xml)
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for **XQuery Update**, which is also supported by Saxon and will make this much easier. This copies the input file, but with few modifications you could also directly change your original document.

```
(: Copy the input file :)
copy $result := doc("file:test.xml")
modify (
  for $definition in $result//definition
  return (
    (: Create new example element, and add it after the definition :)
    insert node element example {
      $definition/example/quote,
      $definition/source
    } after $definition,
    (: Throw away the old elements :)
    delete nodes $definition/(example, source)
  )
)
return $result/dict/word
```

Be aware that this does not fix the broken input in case of the misplaced dot, but I didn't see any approach to do so in your code, either.

In case you prefer a  **version without update statements**, there's still no need for a complex approach using recursive functions:

```
for $word in doc("file:test.xml")/dict/word
return element word {
  for $sense in $word/sense
  return element sense {
    for $definition in $sense/definition
    return (
      element definition { $definition/text() },
      element example { $definition/(example/quote, source) }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens. My actual code is more complex than what I showed above and I can't use xQueryUpdate in this particular case — but both of your suggestions work and I am very grateful for them.